# mitmproxy: disable SSL-ed content inspection but process the rest

Tags: ssl, mitmproxy

Using mitmproxy on OS X.

I'd like to disable/enable SSL inspection only/for a set of hosts. I want to be able to see non-SSL-inspected flows in the Flows list and be processed as usual.

`allow_hosts` / `ignore_hosts` options disables inspection for non/matching flows but those are 
then omitted from Flows list.

Is it possible? Am I missing some mitmproxy option?

For reference, Charles Proxy can do similar thing with 'SSL Proxying Settings...'

Comment: Instead of the command-line parameters you could develop your own plugin that does what you want by modifying the [TLS pass through example](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/examples/complex/tls_passthrough.py).

Comment: Thank you. Seems like a valid answer to me. Could you post it as answer so I could accept it?

Comment: Also I would appreciate if you hint me how can I follow with flows which tried and failed Tls so their processing is not interrupted and they show up in Flows view as failed. Not raising exception allows to continue with next layer but it seems to fail in turn, flow still not being reported.

Comment: As you see there is a lot of work for changing the linked example to something that works as you want it. Therefore I posted it as comment because it does not actually answers your question. It just shows you the start of the path to your target...